# laravel - Redirecting To External Domains with a string parameter

Tags: laravel, http, redirect, controller

I am developing a Laravel 5.6 project in localhost and I need to redirect it to an external website with a string parameter.
I found this on [laravel 5.6 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#redirecting-external-domains)

> [Redirecting To External Domains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#redirecting-external-domains)

Sometimes you may need to redirect to a domain outside of your application. You may do so by calling the away method, which creates a RedirectResponse without any additional URL encoding, validation, or verification:

```
return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');
```

I used the data from a form and created a variable including the data as requested inside the controller. Then added the parameter at the end line this.

```
return redirect()->away('https://sandbox.payhere.lk/pay/checkout')->with('$Payhere');
```

It redirects to required page and shows the error

> "Error!!! Required String parameter 'rid' is not present "

Comment: Is `rid` meant to equal `$Payhere`?

Comment: No , its an object 
        $Payhere = new Payhere();
I was supposed to send those details as they were sent by a form submit

Comment: I want to use this service 
https://support.payhere.lk/api-&-mobile-sdk/payhere-checkout @RossWilson